# Integration $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2x-1}{x^{2/3}\sqrt{(x+1)((x+1)^3-x)}}\text{d}x=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Here is the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2x-1}{x^{2/3}\sqrt{(x+1)((x+1)^3-x)}}\text{d}x=0.$$
This is an elliptic integral, with such an easy result, maybe some *clever substitutions* or *integrating methods* can solve it, but so far I don't know exactly how to attack it.
**Thought 1**:
To separate the integration interval into two parts:$(0,\frac12]$ and $[\frac12,+\infty)$, for the second one, doing a substitution $x\mapsto \frac1x$ is my first thought(possibly not valid).
**Thought 2**:
It looks 100%, even 90%, like *pseudo elliptic integral*(its anti-derivative is elementary). I think this one is *elementary* as well.
**THOUGHT 3**:
**Maybe this is a very STUPID question. Perhaps some mathematical softwares can done it(especially for Mathematica). For some good reasons, I can't use them.**
Waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $$f(x,t) = \frac{2 x-1}{x^{2/3} \sqrt{(x+1) \left((x+1)^3-t x\right)}} \qquad I(t) = \int_0^\infty f(x,t) dx$$
with $g(x,t) = \frac{3 \left(x^2+x\right)}{2 x-1}f$, one checks
$$3t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + f+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}= 0$$
so $$3tI'(t)+I(t) = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dx = -g(\infty,t)+g(0,t) = 0$$
solving this ODE gives $I(t) = Ct^{-1/3}$. The function $t^{-1/3}$ blows up near $t=0$, but our $I(t)$ is continuous at $t=0$, this forces $C=0$. So $I(t)\equiv 0$ for $t$ near $0$. QED.

Comment: @SetnessRamesory It's in general difficult to reverse this method to construct similar $f(x,t)$.

Comment: This gives the same vibe as [Ramanujan's trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3286897/515527). Can you give more insight on how did you came up with that function? (I guess it wasn't your first choice to put $t$ there).

Comment: @Zacky For some theoretical reason, I am afraid there is no obvious relevance between this and the link, except we used the same names $x,t$ and $f(x,t)$. Yes, you can put $t$ in many different places, $f(x,t)$ can be $$\tag{*}\frac{2 x-t}{x^{2/3} \sqrt{(x+1) \left((x+1)^3-t x\right)}} \quad \frac{2t x-1}{x^{2/3} \sqrt{(x+t) \left((x+t)^3-x\right)}}$$ for example. For all such combinations, there is a procedure, Zeilberger algorithm (creative telescoping), for computing a corresponding $g$ (guaranteed to exist) thus an ODE for $I(t)$, in general however has high order (4 or 5) ...cont

Comment: .... The order and complexities of resulting ODE cannot be predicted in advance. I tried some different such $f(x,t)$, only this one produces a nice 1st order ODE for $I(t)$. This is of course anticipated, since we can't expect for every $f(x,t)$ such as $(*)$, the corresponding $I(t)$ to have a nice result.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to solve it directly.
For $|t|$ large enough, let
$$
\tag{1}J\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2x-1}{x^{2/3}\sqrt{(x+1)((x+1)^3-x/t^2)} }\text{d}x.
$$
Firstly, apply the substitution $y=xt$, and
$$
(1)={t^{2/3}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2y-t}{y^{2/3}\sqrt{(y+t)((y+t)^3-y)} }\text{d}y.
$$
Secondly, let $z=y^{1/3}$, and
$$
(1)=-3t^{2/3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t-2z^3}{\sqrt{(z^3+t)((z^3+t)^3-z^3)} }\text{d}z.
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{t-2z^3}{\sqrt{(z^3+t)((z^3+t)^3-z^3)} }
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left ( \frac{2z^3+z+2t}{z^3-z+t}  \right )^3}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \frac{2z^3+z+2t}{z^3-z+t}.
$$
Eventually, we apply the substitution
$$
s= \frac{2z^3+z+2t}{z^3-z+t}.
$$
Since $z\in[0,\infty)$, $s\in(2,2]$. Therefore $J(t)$ must be $0$. For complex $t$, these substitutions need to relate contour integration. But it's also good to show that $J(t)=0$.

---

One checks,
$$
\int_{\sqrt{5}-2}^{1} \frac{2x-1}{x^{2/3}\sqrt{(1-x^2)
(x^2+4x-1)} }\text{d}x=0.
$$

---

Actually, by performing substitution $ s=\frac{2z^a+z+2t}{z^a-z+t},a>1$ ($a$ no need to be an integer), we obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(a-1)x-1}{x^{1-1/a}\sqrt{(x+1)\left((x+1)^3-tx^\frac3a\right)} }\text{d}x\equiv 0.
$$

- Setting $a=5,6,12$, then the following three integrals are derived.
  $$
  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4x-1}{x^{4/5}\sqrt{(x+1)\left ( 
  (x+1)^3+x^\frac35\right ) } }\text{d}x=0,\\
  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{5x-1}{x^{5/6}\sqrt{(x+1)\left ( 
  (x+1)^3+\sqrt{x}\right ) } }\text{d}x=0,\\
  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{11x-1}{x^{11/12}\sqrt{(x+1)\left ( 
  (x+1)^3+\sqrt[4]{x}\right ) } }\text{d}x=0.
  $$
- For non-integer $a$: set $a=\frac{9}{2}$, and
  $$
  \int_{0}^{\infty}
  \frac{7x^3-2}{x^{1/3}\sqrt{(x^3+1)\left ( (x^3+1)^3-t x^2 \right ) } } 
  \text{d}x\equiv0.
  $$
  And we deduce the final one
  $$
  \int_{0}^{\infty}
  \frac{(7x^3-2)f\left(\frac{tx^2}{(1+x^3)^3}\right)}{x^{4/3}\sqrt{1+x^3} } 
  \text{d}x\equiv0.
  $$
  Where $f(x)$ could be almost any function that makes the integral convergent.